# Client Project uses class of Webservice Project

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, visual-studio-2012

- Im using Visual Studio 2012 to create a Web service demo

[image]

- Webservice Project: includes a fragment class

  ```
  class Fragment
  {
  private:
      numerator;
      denominator;
  public:
      void setX();
      void setY();
      ....
      ....
  }
  ```

  and a Web method

  ```
  [Web method]
  public float(Fragment a, Fragment b)
  {
      // Add two fragments
      return ...
  }
  ```
- Client Project: References to Webservice Project

How can i do if i need to use class Fragment in Webservice Project like this?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start your web service on your localhost or deploy it to a server.  Take that URL and in your Windows Form project you need to Add Service Reference to wherever your web service is running.

[image]

[image]